# How to execute a subroutine whose name is just known in runtime, in Fortran 90?

Tags: command-line-arguments, fortran90, subroutine

Suppose I have a program in Fortran with various subroutines, I don't know *a priori* all the subroutines, and an user supplies the name of one of them via command-line, just as follows:

```
    program subroutine_name
```

Therefore, I store the *subroutine_name* in a **character** variable. In this way, I can't declare a **external** variable to store the subroutine. So, how can I call it just knowing its name? Is it possible by this way, or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a way to write a Fortran statement such as

```
call character_variable_containing_subroutine_name
```

It goes against the grain of statically-typed compiled languages such as Fortran to provide that sort of facility.

Of course, if you had asked *can I provide an input argument to a Fortran program which will, at run-time, determine the execution path the program takes* then the answer is *of course*. I'll ignore any complications of your situation and suppose that you want to call one of `sin`, `cos` or `tan`.

First, capture the text of the argument to the program into a character variable:

```
character(len=*) :: user_choice
...
call get_command_argument(1,user_choice)
...
select case (user_choice)
case ('sin')
   ... do stuff with sin
case ('cos')
   ... do stuff with cos
case ('tan')
   ... do stuff with tan
case default
   ... do whatever
end select
```

You could make this more elaborate by using procedure pointers.  For example, you might define:

```
pointer :: rp
interface
 real function rp(inval)
    real, intent(in) :: inval
  end function rp
end interface
```

and then replace the first version of the `select case` construct by something like:

```
select case (user_choice)
case ('sin')
   rp => sin
case ('cos')
   rp => cos
case ('tan')
   rp => tan
case default
   ... do whatever
end select
```

This might simplify later code.  I guess it might also make it more complicated.

Note that I haven't tested any of these fragments, my syntax might be a little wonky.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I got what you meant. It is completely clear for me for intrisic functions, since I know all them, therefore it is possible make a choice based on the user input using a select case, as your example shows. But in my case, the user written a custom procedure and compiled it together with my program. Then I would like to know if the user can choose any name for this routine and pass this name for me as an argument (on a file, for example). As you answered, it is not possible. Thank you.

Comment: old, but this answer doesnt really answer question. You want dynamic share library reads. Look into dl_open, which is a c function but you can find fortran wrappers. This will let you query contents of a library and call functions you find there. If you make a library of functions with a standard interface or possible with a naming convention for the interface you can use this to dynamically call functions that aren't know or even didn't exist at compile time.